# How do I refresh Data Store data in Ember.Js?

Tags: ember.js

How do I get fresh data from the server/DS in ember without reloading a page?

here is the updated component for ember

```
 import Component from '@ember/component';
import { set } from '@ember/object';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { alias } from '@ember/object/computed';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),


  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    let alertColor = this.alertColor;
  this.refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.isDestroyed || this.isDestroying) return;

      this.router.refresh();
    }, 3_000);
  }

 })
```

this is the route... I think. There are other ones but this I think is the one it uses. Im not positive though. Theres also a component which i deleted because Stackoverflow said there wasnt enough details and mostly code...so thats why Im adding all this text here

```
import AddThis from '../mixins/add-this';
import getQueryVariable from '../utils/get-query';
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import { get } from '@ember/object';

export default Route.extend(AddThis, {
  model: function(args) {
    this._super(...arguments);

    return this.store.findRecord('landing-page', args.id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(...arguments);
    const  href = get(model, 'uri') +
                  window.location.search +
                  window.location.hash,
           id = getQueryVariable('id');

    if (id && !isNaN(id) && get(model, 'cardPageType') === '2') {
      this.transitionTo('image', get(model, 'id'), 0, id);
    }

    // @TODO Not 100% clear on what this is for
    if (get(model, 'uri')) {
      window.history.replaceState('', get(model, 'title'), href);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    goToVideo: function(id) {
      this.transitionTo('video', id);
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: that's not a model, that's a component. 

how are you fetching data?

Comment: hold on Ill add the model

Comment: how are you initially fetching the data?

Comment: I dont know...would that be in routes?

Comment: Its using REST i know that...

Comment: it could be in a route -- what's that look like?

Comment: OK i added the route that I think its using

Comment: what's the landing-page?
the route you pasted isn't actually loading any data -- just creating data

Comment: its just a template as far as i can tell...what am i looking for?

Comment: is your app open source? would be good to see details

Comment: otherwise, is there a file at app/routes/landing-page.js?

Comment: yes Illl add the landing-page.js route...

Comment: OK I added app/routes/landing-page.js

Comment: also, feel free to ignore me, if you know what you're doing, but it seems like you're struggling to understand how the different pieces of the framework interact with each other. I highly recommend _reading_ through the official tutorial: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/part-1/

It is top-notch!

Answer (score 0):

Since your loading data in the `landing-page` route, you can use the [RouterService](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/RouterService) to [refresh](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/4.1/classes/RouterService/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh) the route.

For example, whenever you want to refresh our data fetched from a route, you do the following:

```js
import { service } from '@ember/service';
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class Demo extends Component {
  @service router;

  refreshMe = () => {
    this.router.refresh('landing-page');
    // or to refresh all routes:
    // this.router.refresh();
  }
}
```

```
<button {{on 'click' this.refreshMe}}>
  Refresh Me
</button>
```

Note that prior to ember-source@4.1, you'll need to install this polyfill: https://github.com/Windvis/ember-router-service-refresh-polyfill
(which supports all the way back to ember-source@3.4, which is > 3.5 years ago, at the time of writing)

---

edit: demonstrating how to use the legacy syntax and refreshing every 60s.

```js
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

// ...
export default Component.extend({
  // ...
  router: service(),

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    // ...

    
    this.refreshInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (this.isDestroyed || this.isDestroying) return;

      this.router.refresh();
    }, 60_000);
  }

  willDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.refreshInterval);
  }
```

Docs:

- [`@ember/component`](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/release/classes/Component)
- [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
- [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242991/discussion-on-answer-by-nullvoxpopuli-how-do-i-refresh-data-store-data-in-ember).

Comment: youre saying that the model should be updating though once the router is refreshed?

Comment: that is correct, yeah